# /proc/cpuinfo "cache" category: L1, L2 or total?

Tags: cpu, cache

When I look in /proc/cpuinfo, one of the lines tells me I have 6144 KB of cache. Is this L1 cache, L2 cache, or the sum of both of them?

In any case, how do I find out how much L1 and L2 cache my system has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is L2 Cache.  6144KB is actually 6MB.  You can easily check it on the Wiki or on CPU manufacturer's page.

Answer (score 15):

Use `lscpu`. It's in Debian package “util-linux”.

Comment: And if we are not running Debian?

Comment: @Karlson: use your package manager to get that package. It is pretty widespread.

Comment: @Mat Assuming of course that the distribution you're running is new enough to have it and secondly that you have `root` or `sudo` permissions on the system to install it.

Comment: `lscpu` has existed since 2008 according to its copyright info in the source code, `util-linux` has been around since at least 2006. `lscpu` only depends on `libc` and the dynamic linker. If you don't have root (and can't build the source), just extract it from a binary package for a reasonably similar distro and chances are it'll work. Sure there are other options, but that's a pretty good answer to the question "how do I find out how much Lx cache I have?".

Comment: @Mat I am currently working with the version of RHEL that was released back in 2003 and it does have `util-linux` installed but no `lscpu`.  I understand that `lscpu` can be downloaded and compiled but the my point is that assuming that a person can use a command from particular distro or install it on the system he's using is at the very least presumptuous.  Glad the solution worked for the OP.

Comment: @Karlson: you can't expect answers to cover the whole range of Linux variants that have existed since Linux 0.99. This one, quite pragmatically, answers the question with a widely available tool today. It is good. (Better than saying "Check Wikipedia and your CPU manufacturer's website in my opinion.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `dmidecode`. `dmidecode -t cache` should give you the info about the caches present and their individual sizes (also checkout the other options of `dmidecode`, a very useful tool).